# Which set is this black LEGO Technic car with skull and fire stickers?

Tags: set-identification, technic

Please help me to identify the LEGO set. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This car looks like the secondary/alternative model from set# 8167, "Jump Riders":

[image: s]

[image]

Comment: I see you edited your answer and it appears that we had the same idea. I'll go ahead and delete my answer, as it's not needed now.

Comment: I suspected the alternative model, so looked through the pdf instructions and discovered it.  I don't mind if you leave your answer, you may get some points out of it.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did! I guess I'll go ahead and un-delete it, mine does include a link that might be helpful I guess.

Comment: Thank you guys!!

Comment: @Angel - You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

This an alternate build from set [8167 LEGO Jump Riders](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8167-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) as seen in the instruction booklet.

[image]

Comment: I'll even be good sport and "1-up" your correct answer :)